# magento 2 how can I overwrite ar_SA.xml language symbol file?

Tags: magento2, overrides, multicurrency, currency-symbol

I want to overwrite this file in my module.

```
vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/ar_SA.xml
```

How can I archive this ?

Comment: Any solutions buddy ?